# mysql generating dynamic url using id of the table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to generate the dynamic url by getting the id of table and other fields. but for this url i need only id

my query is working but i need the id value for every record in this `[CARD ID] http://mysite.com/webaplication/postcard/view?id=[CARD ID]&shared`

```
SELECT
            `user`.`first_name` 'First Name',
            `user`.`last_name` 'Last Name',
             CASE `card`.`shared` WHEN 1 THEN 'http://mysite.com/webapplication/card/view?id=**`card`.`id`**&shared' ELSE 'No URL' END 'URL',   
            `card`.`created` 'Created', 
            CASE `card`.`shared` WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END 'Shared'

        FROM
            `user`, `card`
        WHERE `card`.`id` =`user`.`id`
        GROUP BY
            `card`.`id`
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Use CONCAT function.

```
(...)
CASE `card`.`shared` WHEN 1 THEN CONCAT('http://mysite.com/webapplication/card/view?id=', `card`.`id`, '&shared') ELSE 'No URL' END 'URL',
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Comment: quick qn. can you pls tell me how to get all the time(for every record) url not just when it is 1..